# Database Choice for a CSV file

Tags: sql, database, database-design, nosql

I have a CSV file.

- It has 5 columns, 4000 rows.
- The database will have a single table, and each year I will add a new  table to the database.
- The tables itself will never be updated, they will be only created once.
- I expect many multiple reads, queries at the same time.
- There won't be any complex queries. Queries will be basically filtering on only one column.
- The users will use sorting on one column.

Based on this, my gut feeling tells me that I should use a SQL solution, like MySQL or PostgreSQL. I am wondering your thoughts, should I use SQL, NoSQL or something else (Redis maybe?)

Comment: what are your performance requirements? latency and throughput?

Comment: If the CSV file is small enough, you don't need a database. Just read the file into memory, and write some logic to filter the array of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, MySQL. Providing you have enough DB storage.